# EF 4.3 Reverse Code First: Eager loaded related entities are null

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to access some related entities using navigation properties. I've turned off Lazy Loading and am using the `Include()` method available `using System.Data.Entity` to Eager Load the related entities. However my related entities are null when the view loads.

I believe the relationships have been properly configured what am I missing?

**Calling Method**

```
public IQueryable<JobRecord> GetAll()
{
    return _dataContext.Set<JobRecord>()
       .Include(t => t.CompanyInfo);
}
```

**Context**

```
public class Application_Context : DbContext, IDataContext
{
public Gyroview_Context():base("Application_Entities")
{ 
    Database.SetInitializer<Application_Context>(null);
    Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}

    public DbSet<CompanyInfo> CompanyInfoes { get; set; }
public DbSet<JobRecord> JobRecords { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CompanyInfoMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new JobRecordMap());

    modelBuilder.Entity<JobRecord>()
            .HasOptional(r => r.CompanyInfo)
            .WithMany(c => c.JobRecords)
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.CompanyID);
}

public IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
    return base.Set<TEntity>();
}
}
```

**JobRecord**

```
public class JobRecord
{
public JobRecord()
{
        this.CompanyInfo = new CompanyInfo();
}

    public Nullable<int> CompanyID { get; set; }
public int Jobid { get; set; }

public virtual CompanyInfo CompanyInfo { get; set; }
}
```

**JobRecord Map**

```
public class JobRecordMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<JobRecord>
{
    public JobRecordMap()
    {
    // Primary Key
    this.HasKey(t => t.Jobid);

    // Table & Column Mappings
    this.ToTable("JobRecord");
    this.Property(t => t.CompanyID).HasColumnName("CompanyID");
    this.Property(t => t.Jobid).HasColumnName("Jobid");

    // Relationships    

        this.HasOptional(t => t.CompanyInfo)
    .WithMany(t => t.JobRecords)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.CompanyID);
}
}
```

**CompanyInfo**

```
public class CompanyInfo
{
    public CompanyInfo()
    {
        this.JobRecords = new List<JobRecord>();    
    }

    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<JobRecord> JobRecords { get; set; } 
}
```

**CompanyInfo Map**

```
public class CompanyInfoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<RigViewCompanyInfo>
{
    public CompanyInfoMap()
    {
    // Primary Key
    this.HasKey(t => t.CompanyID);

    // Properties
    this.Property(t => t.CompanyName)
    .HasMaxLength(255);

    this.Property(t => t.Address)
    .HasMaxLength(255);


    // Table & Column Mappings
    this.Property(t => t.CompanyID).HasColumnName("CompanyID");
    this.ToTable("CompanyInfo");
    this.Property(t => t.CompanyName).HasColumnName("CompanyName");
    this.Property(t => t.Address).HasColumnName("Address");

}
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured this one out after creating a `Database First` solution using the same POCOs created by the Code First `Reverse Engineer Power Tool`.

The related entities were coming out null due to the navigation property (related entity) being new'd up on the constructor; this was overwriting the entity and making it null.

I'm not sure why the `Reverse Engineer Power Tool` creates the POCO with the constructor as I've not had the need to do this with `Database First`, but the constructor can be removed all together.

I was not able to catch this earlier because the razor view was throwing a null reference exception on the related entities that were null.

HTH anyone else experiencing the same problem.